# How to find which iOS app corresponds to this hexadecimal string?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

I haven't able to backup my iPhone to my PC for a while. iTunes always gives me the "An error occurred" message and says that it could not complete the backup. Today I had the idea of trying using [iMazing](https://imazing.com/)... and at least it gave me a more explicit error message:

```
An app installed on your device seems to be corrupted and therefore iMazing cannot back up your device.
Details: Error (101) stat error: Illegal byte sequence (92) at path "/.ba/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7CA32BE4-75AB-40CD-B7F3-D0E295F0C8A7/Documents/.Trash" (MBErrorDomain/101)
```

Now, according to other forum posts like [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251877636), it seems that the only to find out which app it was is to go uninstalling them one by one. I am asking here: is there another way? Can I use that hexadecimal string (7CA32BE4-75AB-40CD-B7F3-D0E295F0C8A7) to identify the app in question, or is it uniquely generated for each device?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43494782/3487310) help?  It might give you some info to guide your search.

Comment: But how do I access that path? iMazing won't let me do that in an older backup of my phone, and I don't want to jailbreak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to show the device console in iMazing while the backup is running (possibly by doing the backup in iTunes so iMazing is free to show you the logs)? I'm not positive that you'll see any messages that give you more information about which app it is, but fingers crossed you may see something like "`Finished scanning domain`" and then the AppDomain for the app after the error messages for the stat error.

Or, if you have an older backup of the iPhone from before the errors started, you can see if that string is in the Manifest.plist and see which app it is the Path for.

Comment: I am away from my PC for the next few days, so I won't be able to check this. I seem to remember doing something similar yesterday though, and searching for the UUID, I did find some error messages but none with the app's name. I'll post here again once I have checked it out.

Comment: Well, you were right. Searching the logs, I can definitely find the apps that were giving the error. Unfortunately, there are *a lot* of them. I can't explain how so many apps seem to be "corrputed" (according to IOS's backup agent) and yet still work fine...