# Lots of iOS apps apparently "corrupted", yet they work

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

This is on an Iphone 8, iOS 14.8.1.

As mentioned in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435414/how-to-find-which-ios-app-corresponds-to-this-hexadecimal-string), I haven't been able to back up my Iphone to my PC using iTunes for a while. Using iMazing, I managed to locate the error message it was giving:

```
An app installed on your device seems to be corrupted and therefore iMazing cannot back up your device.
Details: Error (101) stat error: Illegal byte sequence (92) at path "/.ba/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7CA32BE4-75AB-40CD-B7F3-D0E295F0C8A7/Documents/.Trash" (MBErrorDomain/101)
```

And thanks to the user who answered my previous question, I managed to locate the app causing trouble by checking the Iphone's console logs. Right before the previus error message, it shows something like this (the errors below aren't actually caused by the same app than the above ones; more on this later):

```
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001203 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Error>: fstatat failed at <private> (<private>): [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= Dumping diagnostics for /.ba/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A2218C4-F4A7-40C9-8395-4938C2E933A2/Documents/44832251.png (0)
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001203 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= access(R_OK) failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001203 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= access(F_OK) failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001203 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= stat failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001203 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= getattrlist failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= fstatfs: bsize 4096, iosize 1048576, blocks 15617309, bfree 2020140, bavail 334059, files 624692360, ffree 624219915, fsid {805306434, 24}, owner 0, type 24, flags 0x44809089, fssubtype 0, flags_ext 0x0
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= readdir_r found file entry (128), type 8, ino 24665880, namelen 12, reclen 40
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(Sandbox)[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: 5 duplicate reports for fitcored deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.contactsd
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(Sandbox)[0] <Error>: System Policy: BackupAgent2(29237) deny(1) system-privilege 14000
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= openbyid_np({805306434, 24}, 24665880) failed: [1: Operation not permitted]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= fsctl(APFSIOC_GET_CLONE_INFO) failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001203 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001203 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= Failed to open the file raw encrypted: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= Finished dumping diagnostics for /.ba/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A2218C4-F4A7-40C9-8395-4938C2E933A2/Documents/44832251.png
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= Dumping diagnostics for /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A2218C4-F4A7-40C9-8395-4938C2E933A2/Documents/44832251.png (0)
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001123 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= access(R_OK) failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001123 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= access(F_OK) failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001123 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= stat failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001123 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= getattrlist failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= fstatfs: bsize 4096, iosize 1048576, blocks 15617309, bfree 2011324, bavail 334059, files 624692360, ffree 624219915, fsid {16777219, 24}, owner 0, type 24, flags 0x14809098, fssubtype 0, flags_ext 0x0
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= readdir_r found file entry (128), type 8, ino 24665880, namelen 12, reclen 40
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= openbyid_np({16777219, 24}, 24665880) failed: [1: Operation not permitted]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001123 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= fsctl(APFSIOC_GET_CLONE_INFO) failed: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_checksum_verify:5097: disk0s1s2: failed: cksum 0xcdafce8cb937f174, oid 0x4cf342165cffdec5, o_xid 0x97cd1856acf71ed9, o_type 0x588a2f8e, o_subtype 0xf61b32b1, size 4096
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: nx_corruption_detected_int:55: disk0s1 Container corruption detected by obj_checksum_verify:5105!
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone kernel(apfs)[0] <Notice>: obj_read:4718: disk0s1s2: oid 0x3276f3 flags 0x10001123 0x0 type 0x10000003/0xe paddr 0xd259 error verifying checksum
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= Failed to open the file raw encrypted: [92: Illegal byte sequence]
Feb 12 19:54:45 iPhone BackupAgent2[29237] <Notice>: =diag= Finished dumping diagnostics for /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A2218C4-F4A7-40C9-8395-4938C2E933A2/Documents/44832251.png
```

Now, the first time this happened, I thought that it would enough to delete the app and that'd be it... but after deleting it, I tried backing it up again... and a different app started giving a similar error.

(Hence, the above errors are from two different apps. I forgot which one was the first; the second one is Shazam. I deleted Shazam and a different app started with the errors).

The strange thing, though, is that I can still use all these apps; in fact, I use them daily with no issues, which I'd guess it would be impossible if their data was corrupted. Also, how come there are *so many* apps showing this problem?

Is there any way to solve this, other than deleting and reinstalling every single app in my phone?